# How to add a new field to joomla register form?

Tags: joomla

I am trying to make a joomla plugin, but I have few questions that I haven't found any answer.

What the plugin has to do: add a new field in register form(let's say Cell Number), and on form submit insert that cell number in database.

My documentation is this [tutorial](https://docs.joomla.org/Creating_a_profile_plugin).

Questions:

- How do you add a new field in register form? xml file is done, but I am not sure how to write the php code...(please help). What this code do?

  $form->setFieldAttribute('something', 'required', $this->params->get('profile-require_something') == 2, 'profile5');
- How do I get the cell number variable from that form? `$jinput = JFactory::getApplication()->input;` ?

Pleas help me with few tips. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just copy the code that is there. What will happen is that the php will automatically loop through all the fields in your xml.

```
$form->setFieldAttribute('something', 'required', $this->params->get('profile-require_something') == 2, 'profile5');
```

Is taking the field with the name `something` and changing it to be `required`  if the parameter called `profile-require_something` is set to 2 .  `profile5` is the name of the xml file and the php file for the example plugin. It's the actual name of the plugin. You can have many profile plugins if you want but each needs its own name.

To get the a value you would do something like

`$jinput->getString('cell_number', '');`